# ¿Qué significa el simbolo '~' en Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

¿Que significa este símbolo?: `~`

Lo he visto que aparece cuando se van a instalar algunos componentes como por ejemplo:

```
php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
```

o cuando hago un cd en la raíz:

```
analistasistemas-VirtualBox / # cd 
analistasistemas-VirtualBox ~ #
```

¿Qué nombre tiene el simbolo?

Comment: El símbolo en ingles se llama _tilde_, para que puedas buscar información mas completa.

Comment: Respondiendo a la pregunta de qué nombre tiene: [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) en inglés y [virgulilla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgulilla) en castellano

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~` es un símbolo llamado [***virgulilla***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ) que en los sistemas operativos UNIX se refiere al valor de la variable `$HOME`, esto es, el directorio del usuario que está logueado.

Permite de esta forma referenciar ese directorio directamente, sin tener que escribir `/home/usuario/` cada vez.

Si miras el fichero `/etc/passwd`, allá verás cómo está definido para cada uno de los usuarios. Normalmente es `/home/nombre_de_usuario`, si bien para `root` suele ser `/`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues bien, cuando Bash (u otra shell, pues [es algo definido por POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423984/40596)) lee `~` fuera de comillas, lo expande automáticamente por el valor que se encuentra en `/etc/passwd` para el usuario que lo está ejecutando.

Por tanto, en tu caso particular, al decir:

```
php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
#   ^
```

Lo que se hará es:

```
php /home/tu_usuario/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: parece mentira que seas mod de Spanish SE xD. [virgulilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ) no virguilla

Comment: @blonfu también soy patosillo jaja

Comment: yo siempre había dicho ALT+126 por mis años de juventud en windows :)

Comment: aca se llama ñuflo...

Comment: Algunos (en México), le llamamos "churrito".

Comment: ustedes son unos n00b, todo el mundo sabe que se llama cola de chancho (que es como le decimos al cerdo en chile)

Answer (score 8):

El '~' es el Path absoluto(ruta) del usuario que estes usando, es decir la carpeta personal del usuario con el que estas loqueado.

Por ejemplo, me logueo con el usuario: foo
si pongo

```
cd ~
```

es lo mismo que poner

```
cd /home/foo
```

cuando hacer un 'cd' en la raíz lo que hace es añadir automáticamente 'cd .'
si haces un 'ls -a' verás que hay un directorio(simbólico) que pone './' que apunta al directorio donde estas.

```
cd
```

es lo mismo que poner

```
cd ./
```

Y lo otro ya es el comportamiento del PS1(prompt), si quieres saber mas del PS1 te dejo el link [aqui](http://es.tldp.org/COMO-INSFLUG/COMOs/Bash-Prompt-Como/Bash-Prompt-Como-2.html).

Answer (score 6):

En Bash, el `~` o "tilde" (en inglés) es un caracter especial cuyo uso más habitual es el indicar de manera breve la carpeta especial `$HOME` que corresponde al directorio personal del usuario. Cuando hacemos algo como esto: `cd ~` si somos el usuario `pedro` seguramente iremos a parar a la carpeta `/home/pedro`. Es tan común este uso que se pierde de vista que el `~` es una característica de Bash para expandir el nombre de una carpeta con múltiples usos bien documentados en [**Tilde Expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

Algunos usos:

- `~` --> el valor de `$HOME`
- `~/foo` --> `$HOME/foo`
- `~fred/foo` --> La subcarpeta `foo` en el `$HOME`del usuario `fred`.
- `~+` --> `$PWD` El directorio actual

Bash tiene una pila donde se registran las carpetas dónde hemos ido navegando, podemos usar `~` para navegar dicha pila (ver comando `dirs`):

- ~-  --> `$OLDPWD` El directorio anterior en el que hemos estado
- ~1 --> lo mismo que el comando `'dirs +1'` (el directorio posterior en la pila)
- ~-1 --> lo mismo que el comando `'dirs -1'` (el directorio anterior en la pila)

Comment: +1 Por hablar en términos "Tilde Expansion", citar la documentación, hablar sobre las pilas de carpetas y el uso del `~<usuario>` :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Es la ruta a la carpeta personal de tu usuario (la que normalmente es accesible a través de la variable de entorno $HOME).

Por ejemplo, si tu usuario es "pepe", su carpeta personal estará en
/home/pepe y al poner `cd ~` te dirigirás a dicha carpeta.

Como punto a tener en cuenta, la carpeta del superusuario (root),  no está en /home/root, sino directamente en la raíz de tu sistema, es decir, en /root.

Comment: Está en `/root` porque está así definido en `/etc/passwd`, pero bien podría ser otro valor. Por convención se recomienda `/root`, claro está.

Answer (score 2):

Es la ruta relativa a la carpeta personal del usuario.

Por ejemplo:

> Ruta absoluta: `/home/usuario/imagen.jpg`
>
> Ruta relativa: `~/imagen.jpg`

Comment: Eso no es del todo cierto, ~/imagen.jpg sigue siendo absoluta, relativa sería ./imagen.jpg

Answer (score 2):

significa la ruta de la carpeta home del usuario **~**

si tenemos en nuestra consola algo como:

```
miuser@server:~$
```

si ejecutas `pwd` te devolvera la ruta `/home/miuser` ya que te esta colocando la ruta del usuario

Un ejemplo es si te encuentras en una carpeta **x** y quieres devolver a la carpeta del usuario , puedes ejecutarlo con el comando :

```
miuser@server:/var/www/$ cd ~
```

esto aplica para todos los usuarios  el buscara la carpeta del usuario con que estes trabajando con algunas diferencias en **root** si no tiene esa carpeta creada

Puede que para el usuario **root** sea un poco diferente este te retornara a la ruta `/root`

ahora si tienes dudas exactamente a que ruta va a ir, ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
echo ~
```

te devolvera la ruta que esta apuntando

Answer (score 0):

NOTA
~ es el símbolo virgulilla que en los sistemas operativos Linux seria una abreviacion de /home/tu-user ó de / (root)

Si escribes en la consola ~ (AltGr + 4) desde el usuario root te mostrara por pantalla

```
bash: /root: Es un directorio
```

ó

```
bash: /home/gnuxdar: Es un directorio
```

si lo haces desde tu usuario normal

Por lo tanto tu linea:

```
php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
```

seria igual que si escribieras:

```
php /home/gnuxdar/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet   (gnuxdar es mi user)
```

y en el caso de

```
analistasistemas-VirtualBox / # cd 
analistasistemas-VirtualBox ~ #
```

seria lo mismo que escribieras

```
cd /home/gnuxdar
```

de todas maneras escribe en tu consola ~ desde cualquier ruta
y luego le das pwd y te mostrara el home de tu usuario