# ¿Cómo establecer variables de entorno en Solus OS?

Tags: linux

Estoy intentando agregar variables de entorno para correr el instalador de `laravel` en `Solus`, pero no encuentro información clara de cómo hacerlo.

Solo encuentro información sobre el archivo `.bashrc` y de la ruta `/usr/share/defaults/etc/profile.d`, pero no sé qué archivo debo crear o modificar, ya que no quiero mal lograr mi `Linux` como me pasó hace tiempo con otro por no saber cuál archivo modificar para establecer `variables de entorno`.

En el archivo `.bashrc` solo contiene esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste poner `export tu_variable=hola` en tu archivo `.bashrc` y luego abrir una terminal y ver si puedes hacer un `echo $tu_variable`?

Comment: Acabo de hacer lo que pusiste, pero sigue sin funcionar, se supone que en el momento en el que yo escriba la palabra `laravel` tiene que arrojar un resultado, en cambio muestra que el comando no se encontró.

Comment: Y al hacer el `echo` de la variable con la ruta que se necesita para que acepte ese comando, sí me la imprime... pero si abro otra terminal nueva y hago el `echo`, me lo muestra vacío y ya no se encuentra en la lista que muestra al ejecutar `printenv`

Comment: Sería útil que pusieras el contenido de tu archivo `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Y no, no se supone que cuando escribas la palabra "laravel" te muestre el resultado. Una cosa es una variable y otra cosa es un token. Si quieres que te ejecute laravel con un simple comando, crea un enlace simbólico del archivo donde está laravel hacia la carpeta `/local/usr/bin`

Comment: ya lo agregué @mrc_es

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres cargar una variable de entorno a tu sesión de bash añade, con algún editor o añadiéndole el stdout de algún programa, en el archivo '~/.bashrc' lo siguiente.

```
...
export tu_variable1="valor de tu variable1"
export tu_variable2="valor de tu variable2"
...
```

Reiniciando tu sesión de bash, puedes revisar que tu variable está, ejecutando:

```
echo $tu_variable1
```

Ahora, por los comentarios, supongo que quieres correr laravel como si fuera un comando. Entonces necesitas saber la ruta de donde se encuentra su ejecutable, por ejemplo, `/ruta/de/laravel`

### Enlace simbólico.

Entonces creas un enlace simbólico de esa ruta hacía tu carpeta de `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ ln -s /ruta/de/laravel /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

Y, por si las dudas, revisas que en tu PATH esté la ruta de `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin  # te tiene que salir algo de este estilo
#                  |
#                  |________ En este ejemplo puedes ver que está la carpeta "/usr/local/bin"
```

Si está, puedes revisar si está el enlace simbólico que acabas de crear en la carpeta con un `ls -l`

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep laravel
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4 Dec 11 21:25 laravel1 -> /la/ruta/de/tu/laravel
```

En caso de que no esté en tu variable `PATH` (lo cual sería muy raro), puedes poner dentro de tu archivo `.bashrc`

```
...
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
...
```

Todo, salvo lo del enlace simbólico, era para revisar que todo se estaba ejecutando correctamente. Ya podrías escribir en tu terminal `laravel` y se te ejecutaría.

### Alias en .bashrc

Si, por algún motivo, no quieres hacer un enlace simbólico, puedes crear un alias, en tu archivo `.bashrc`, hacía tu ejecutable de laravel.

```
...
alias laravel='/ruta/completa/hacia/laravel'
...
```

#### Nota (para más placer).

Como el archivo `.bashrc` hace su efecto al iniciar una nueva sesión de bash, entonces puedes hacer dos cosas.

1. La obvia pero aburrida. Cierra abre una consola nueva.
2. En esa misma consola ejecuta el comando: `exec "$BASH"` Y hará algo así como el efecto de "reiniciar" (lo cual es impreciso pero ese no es el tema de tu pregunta).

Comment: agrego una pregunta por si no sabe  [Qué significa el simbolo '~' en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136600/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-simbolo-en-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Para exportar una variable puedes hacerlo de 2 formas:

- Temporal:

  ```
  export php=/usr/bin/php
  ```
- Permanente: agregándolas al archivo `.bashrc`:

  ```
  echo export php=/usr/bin/php >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

  o simplemente con editor de texto agregando la linea al archivo

  ```
  export php=/usr/bin/php
  ```

**Nota:** para la forma Permanente deberás volver a cargar el profile `~/.bashrc` saliendo de la sesión y volviendo a entrar, o bien utilizando el comando: `source ~/.bashrc`.